# sql select same field twice for the same row

Tags: sql

There are two tables one for competition another for teams.

Competition table contains information about the competition, scores, date, and teamIds. (teamsId is important)

```
| Competition | Team1 | Team2 | date
|      5      |  22   |   11  | 01-01-98|
```

Team table contains information about each team, including the team's name. (Teams Name is important)

```
| team Id | TeamName |
|    22   |Barcelona |
|    11   |Manchester|
```

Query:

```
SELECT competition, team1, team2, date, TeamName ta, TeamName as tb
FROM comp 
INNER JOIN teamname ON (team1 = Teamname)
WHERE team1 = 22 Limit 1;
```

So far i get this:

```
| Competition | Team1 | Team2 | date    |ta        |   tb    |  
|      5      |  22   |   11  | 01-01-98|Barcelona |Barcelona|
```

I need this result

```
| Competition | Team1 | Team2 | date    |ta        |tb       |
|      5      |  22   |   11  | 01-01-98|Manchester|Barcelona|
```

How can I return one team name to team1name and the other team name to team2name? without having more than one row.

I would prefer if I don't have to add any new select or union all, as this is just a small piece of the actual query, and on the original query, there is quite a few select and union all already.

Comment: JOIN teams table twice. (Once for each team name!)

Comment: @jarlh i tried that it gives me error "Not unique table/alies)

Comment: Have different table aliases, like t1 and t2.

Comment: @jarlh I tried that in the past I get the error "teamname in field list is ambiguous"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `JOIN` twice!

```
SELECT competition, team1, team2, date, t1.TeamName ta, t2.TeamName as tb
FROM comp 
INNER JOIN team t1 ON (team1 = t1.teamid)
INNER JOIN team t2 ON (team2 = t2.teamid)
WHERE team1 = 22 Limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use join teamname twice

```
 select t3.Competition,t3.Team1,t3.Team2,t3.TeamName as team1,t2.TeamName as team2
from
(
    SELECT c.*,t1.TeamName

    FROM comp c
    left JOIN team t1 ON t1.teamid = c.Team1
) t3 left join team t2 ON t3.Team2 = t2.teamid


  Competition   Team1   Team2   team1          team2
           5     22          11     Barcelona   Manchester
```

Comment: @LukeDS https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5d372201c1f5375eb2bc5ef5a65990a3 check the link it was working